# Yii2: Implementing a Text field with "Quick Pick" Dropdown list

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have been trying to implement a **single** input field which is essentially a text input field combined with functionality of having a list of "quick pick" items from a drop-down.  When an item is selected from the drop-down, the text input is filled in and the text can be edited as usual.

I have reviewed the Yii2 Select2 box (http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) along with its tagging functionality, but it does not quite do the job.  It essentially implements a "fixed" drop-down which - even if you can add free text - you cannot subsequently edit it.

I have also played around with the Typeahead widget (http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/typeahead), but this requires you to type first before some "auto-suggestions" come up.  This is not what I want - I would like the drop-down list to be immediately accessible for "quick picking" (and subsequent text editing if necessary).

There are numerous questions surrounding Yii2 with autocomplete and drop-down boxes, but none I could find have addressed the functionality I described above.  I have also read a number of other questions that use jQuery (etc) but I am looking for a native Yii2 solution if there is one.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:  Best example of the functionality is the Windows' "Run" dialog where most recently used items appeared, however free text is still permitted:

[image: Windows Run "Drop-down quick combo" list]

Comment: Can you draw a picture (or find where it is being used)? It would be more clear to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @EdvinTenovimas - I have edited my question to provide an example.

Comment: This is a little difficult thing. :) What about if dropdown is next to input?

Comment: I was hoping that there was an existing widget that I hadn't found yet  ;)  I see where you're going with the two-field solution - presumably you're alluding to a drop-down that populates the input via Jquery?  I suppose this is doable with something like http://demos.krajee.com/dropdown-x#, but not what I originally had in mind.  Ideally everything would be in the one field.

Comment: I had a little different thing in mind. Using bootstrap to create your desired input. This widget might or might not be able to do that (didn't xhexk all options). Using bootstrap you can technically call it as one field and divided (but still they touch each other).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @EdvinTenovimas.  Will update this thread if I come up with anything.  Hopefully someone else might be able to suggest some easier (i.e. pre-built) alternatives in the mean-time.

Comment: I haven't found one but you actually get some code from other websites with the help of HTML, JavaScript and CSS. If you would like, I could provide a few of them.

Comment: If you think that this would solve the problem, then that would be very helpful of you, thanks!